# When Is it Preferred to Allocate vs Rent an Array?

Tags: c#, performance, memory, .net-core, garbage-collection

I am currently designing a solution, and have found myself in an interesting performance scenario.  I have placed a very simple solution demonstrating this scenario that can be found here:

https://github.com/Mike-EEE/Stash/tree/master/AllocationVsRent

At heart of this issue is allocation vs. rental of an array.  One of the methods found in this solution performs a rental, as seen here:

```
[Benchmark]
public int Rented()
{
    var array = _pool.Rent(2);
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    var result = array[0] + array[1];
    _pool.Return(array);
    return result;
}
```

The other performs an allocation, as seen here:

```
[Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
public int Allocated()
{
    var array = new int[2];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;

    var result = array[0] + array[1];
    return result;
}
```

When running these two benchmarks I get the following results:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.5, OS=Windows 10.0.17763.475 (1809/October2018Update/Redstone5)
AMD Ryzen 7 2700X, 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.0.100-preview5-011568
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.0.0-preview5-27626-15 (CoreCLR 4.6.27622.75, CoreFX 4.700.19.22408), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.0.0-preview5-27626-15 (CoreCLR 4.6.27622.75, CoreFX 4.700.19.22408), 64bit RyuJIT


|    Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD |  Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|---------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|------:|--------:|-------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|    Rented | 29.563 ns | 0.1736 ns | 0.1450 ns |  5.01 |    0.27 |      - |     - |     - |         - |
| Allocated |  5.825 ns | 0.1440 ns | 0.2522 ns |  1.00 |    0.00 | 0.0077 |     - |     - |      32 B |
```

While the `Allocated` benchmark is faster, it does invoke garbage collection.  Whereas for the `Rented` benchmark, it is slower but there is no garbage collection penalty.

So my fundamental question is: which one is preferred?  Is it OK to go with the allocation even though it does produce garbage?  While it is faster, its use still feels dirty to me, excuse the pun.

**Please note**: I cannot use `stackalloc` as my scenario in practice involves calling between two methods, and as I understand it this precludes the use of that.  I am certainly open to any suggestions that I am overlooking to get the best of both worlds here.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: If those arrays are indeed so small, can't you use `stackalloc` represented as a `Span`? And then pass it to the underlying methods?

Comment: Wow @KonradKokosa I thought for sure I had tried this before but was under the impression that `Span` had some weird limitations that kept me from using it from my design.  I will look further into this to see if I can use that.

Comment: Your micro-scenarios don't give enough information to make any conclusion what's better for your situation. There can be many factors dictated by specific requirements (which you didn't provide) and even it's possible that it doesn't matter what approach to use if it has negligible impact on a final result.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov We are in nanosecond land so it's all negligible. :)  I suppose I am more interested in the general theory and approach here.  Is it ever OK to allow allocation if it is faster?  As it does lead to GC, there is a hidden cost there.

Comment: Even nanoseconds matter if they are iterated millions of times. But regardless of this there is no one right approach for all cases - everything depends on requirements. The ultimate adverbs like ever, never, always, etc. aren't applicable for engineering. You can still use allocation like many software do if your performance indicators aren't affected by this - it's simpler and more usual. You can switch to allocation-free approach if you can't achieve desirable performance profile and GC contributes to this situation. There are different types of solutions which use memory in different ways.

Comment: That's good insight and feedback, @DmytroMukalov, thank you!

Comment: More likely the benefits of `ArrayPool` begin when you are allocating large arrays (so they end up in Gen2 -not Gen0- or in the Large Object Heap, which are insanely slower to collect, since they clean up the whole managed heap [Full GC, they call it])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is too much involved with my scenario to explain further (trying to keep it simple here), *I am solving this problem by allowing the end developer to decide whether they want speed or garbage.*

For a little more context, the API I am developing is zero-allocation first and foremost and speed as an important but secondary focus.

In all other calls, the API is zero-allocation and faster than an existing API that I am testing against, with the exception for this call.  So, by default, I will make it zero-allocation to be consistent with the rest of the API, but if the consuming/end developer is OK with garbage and wants those few extra nanoseconds, they can easily allow that instead.